# sending JSON array from android to servlet

Tags: java, android, servlets

I have a problem sending `JSON Array` to `Servle`t from Android. But I am able to send the same `JSON Array` via the Browser. I have spent many hours trying to solve this problem, but can't find a solution.

```
URL = "http://192.168.*.*:8080/Test/TestServlet?q=add&array="
```

And I have add JSON Array at the end:

```
[{"amount":"3","test":"test",...}]
```

**GlassFish** server error:

```
org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 0 of
```

Waiting for reply, thank you.

**Servlet:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String req = request.getParameter("q");


    try 
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver found");

        dbConnect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/***",  
                                                       "root", "***");
        dbStatement = dbConnect.createStatement();

        if (req.equals("add")) {
            String json_array = request.getParameter("array");

            String query = null;
            org.json.JSONArray jArray = new org.json.JSONArray(json_array);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
            {
              org.json.JSONObject obj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
              query = 
                 "INSERT INTO *** (...) VALUES(" + obj.getInt("***") + ",'" +  
                 obj.getString("***") + "','" + obj.getString("***") + "','" +  
                 obj.getString("***") + "'," + obj.getDouble("***") + "," +  
                 obj.getDouble("***") + "," + obj.getDouble("***") + ",'" +  
                 obj.getString("***") + "','"+obj.getString("***")+"','','"+  
                 obj.getString("***") + "')";
            }

            dbStatement.executeUpdate(query);
    ...
```

**Android**

```
protected void sendJson(JSONArray json) 
{
      HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
      HttpResponse response;
      try
      {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());  
        Log.i("JSON before sending", json.toString());

        se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        post.setEntity(se);
        response = client.execute(post);

        /*Checking response */
        if(response!=null)
        {
          InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();   
          //Get the data in the entity
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Comment: What do see when you debug/pring `json_array` in the servlet when sent from Android ?

Comment: at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
 at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
 at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:147)
 at TestServlet.doPost(TestServlet.java:114)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)

Comment: Not this. In servlet you have this line `String json_array = request.getParameter(..`. Just after this, put `System.out.println(json_array) `and see what it prints.

Comment: I have tried it before, it crashes on that line, so no message to print. I guess the problem in HTTP parameters. I probably should do something with this "q=add&array=" in Android part, but I am not sure how exactly. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are using POST from your code. Try using GET. See an example code in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On browser you are trying with GET method whereas in your code you are using POST method. Try using the GET method in your code. Following is a example of GET method to be used with `HttpClient`

```
GetMethod get = new GetMethod("http://www.example.com/page");
method.setQueryString(new NameValuePair[] {
    new NameValuePair("q", "add"),
  new NameValuePair("array", "[{"amount":"3","test":"test"}]"),
});
```

then use `client.execute(post);` to call the server.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your replies. I have decided to do it this way, and it's working:  List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("array", json));

  try
  {
   DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
   httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
   HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
  }

Answer (score 0):

StringEntity will be encoding your [ { } ] to %5B %7B %7D %5D, getParameter on the servlet probably doesn't decode these before you give it to the JsonArray to parse. So url decoding the parameter on the servlet may be the fix you're looking for.